# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ApplicationDbContext' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, objectcontext

I recently upgraded my app to .net core 6 and now I am getting this error in line this code:

```cs
public List<KeyValuePair<string, long>> GetKeys(EntityEntry entry)
{
    var keys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
    var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);

    if (objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues != null)
    {
        keys.AddRange(objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, long>(key.Key, Convert.ToInt64(key.Value))));
    }

    return keys;
}
```

The value this refers to ApplicationDbContext

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the keyName but not sure how to get the keyValue

```
var keyName = entry.CurrentValues.EntityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties
       .Select(x => x.Name).Single();
```

Comment: I think [this](https://long2know.com/2016/07/porting-ef6-to-ef7-or-ef-core/) will help.

Comment: @Ergis thanks the link clarifies why it doesnt work but doesnt exactly give a solution